# Trouble with Linux Mint installation USB - in UEFI mode boots to grub terminal

Tags: linux, linux-mint, uefi

I used Rufus to create USB installation media for Linux Mint 19.2 cinnamon. I chose GPT partition scheme with NTFS. When I boot from the USB (in UEFI mode) it boots to the grub terminal instead of loading the installation program.

In my bios I have CSM disabled, secure boot disabled and I get the same behavior whether or not fast boot is enabled. The computer is an ASUS N56VJ notebook.

The existing disk has win 10 installed dual boot with ubuntu. I'm trying to replace the ubuntu install with mint.

Comment: Are you trying to use persistence? In that case please try without it (persistence =0). That kind of error gives an output as described in [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=42&p=13891342#post13891342). Another possible cause of your problem is that you might have an nvidia graphics chip, that needs the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`.

Comment: I was using ISO mode which was the recommended mode in Rufus. I'm assuming this mode uses persistence? I changed to DD Image mode and now it's working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: _"I'm assuming this mode uses persistence?"_ No, it doesn't, unless you __actively__ change the persistent partition to anything than 0 (i.e. you need to manually change something here -- the default of Rufus in either DD or ISO mode is not to use any persistence). Source: I am the main Rufus developer.